# Supporter badge issue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

Today, first time I logged-in to `math.stackexhange.com`. I have other associated accounts also, so I got $101$ reputation initially. I vote-up one question then suddenly I undo the vote-up. After that it shows me `supporter` badge on my profile. If I am going to [all accounts](http://stackexchange.com/users/1415212/jaguar?tab=accounts) page, the page shows one bronze badge for mathematics account. Isn't it a bug or regular behaviour?

Comment: When I made my first down-vote, I removed it within a few seconds, but still got my Critic badge. It seems that the badge triggers don't have an untrigger mechanism.

Comment: It is by design. Please see:

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2137/is-the-critic-badge-awarded-prematurely

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/is-it-possible-to-lose-a-badge-during-a-recalc

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58053/is-it-possible-to-lose-badges

Comment: @Willie Your comment could be posted as/made to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Willie may be too busy to repost his old comments, I'll write a CW:

- By design, general badges are not revoked. For badges that can be awarded multiple times (such as `Nice Answer` and many others) the system will "get even" with you next time you qualify for the badge. For example, every time your answer reaches a score of 10, it compares the number of your 10+ answers and the number of your `Nice Answer` badges; if the second is less than the first, you get the badge again.
- [Tag-based badges](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges?tab=tags) are processed differently, and may be lost if you no longer qualify for them. [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58053/is-it-possible-to-lose-badges)
- Meta SO has a community-generated [list of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) which explains the eligibility criteria for each badge.

Comment: thanks for posting it.